# Devise with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bundler

The team behind Devise announced via blogpost 
http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/devise-and-rails-4/ that it was releasing a version that is compatible with Rails 4, calling it  '3.0 rc'. In the same blog post, it also said it's releasing `Devise 2.2.4.`

I'm trying to build a Rails 4 app. when I did `gem install Devise`, it installed 2.2.4, not the version compatible with Rails 4.

```
Fetching: devise-2.2.4.gem (100%)
```

Which I assume from the comments in the blogpost about strong parameters is not going to be compatible with Rails 4.

I looked at Devise's github page but it's not obvious to me how to install the version compatible with Rails 4.   Can you assist?

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Note, I tried

```
gem install devise --version 3.0.0.rc1
```

but it said

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'devise' (= 3.0.0.rc1) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: devise
```

Comment: http://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/3.0.0.rc

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Devise is now compatible with Rails 4 out of the box as of the time of this answer.

Our end goal is to have users be able to register, log in and log out of the website. We'll also create a small partial view letting us know if we're logged in or out.

---

### Install the Devise gem.

Open up your `Gemfile` and install the Devise gem.

```
gem 'devise'
```

Then in your terminal run the `bundle install` command to install the gem.

```
$ bundle install
```

### Run some Devise generators to set up the initial configurations.

Run this command from your terminal:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

This generator installs the initializer that configures all of Devise's available settings.

### Generate your User model.

Next we need to generate our User model. I'm going to name it `User` but you can name it whatever you like, just replace `User` with `Whatever`.

```
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
```

### Configure your default URL option for Development.rb

Inside of `config/environments/development.rb`, set the Action Mailer's default URL to localhost:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

### Make sure you have a root route declared in Routes.rb

You need to make sure that `routes.rb` has a default root route - if you don't have one, set it!

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

### Create a partial view to see if we're logged in or not.

Inside of your `views/layouts` folder create a file named `_user_widget.html.erb` and copy this code in:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p>Welcome <%= current_user.email %></p>
  <%= link_to 'Logged In [click to logout]', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
  <p>You are not signed in.</p>
  <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

And invoke it within your layout (`views/layouts/application.html.erb`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>FacebookAuthTest</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

  <%= yield %>

  <%= render 'layouts/user_widget' %>

</body>
</html>
```

---

> **Make sure you stop and restart the server otherwise you will find all sorts of nasty bugs!** It's always best to restart your local
>   server when you update your gemfile or change anything in the
>   environment configuration file.

With all this in place, you should be able to sign up, log in and log out from your very own Rails website.

If you have any questions feel free to leave a comment below and I'll try to help.

Comment: This is quite a terse yet straight forward explanation. Just felt like it deserved a little more than an up vote.

Answer (score 29):

**UPDATE SEPT 17th, 2013**: The master branch is now compatible with Rails 4. No need to search for another version.

Looking at the [github repo](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), it looks like you want version `3.0.0.rc` (no 1). So you'll want

```
gem install devise --version "3.0.0.rc"
```

or, in your gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
```

Comment: I get this `gem install devise-3.0.0.rc
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'devise-3.0.0.rc' (>= 0) in any repository`

Comment: Added the correct commands to my answer, but looks like you got it anyways.

Answer (score 3):

This installed it

```
gem install devise --pre
```

or

```
devise-3.0.0.rc.gem
```

Answer (score 2):

At this point this version of the gem is what you would want to use

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'

Answer (score 1):

Now that the 3.0 version is stable, you can just do:

```
gem install devise
```

or in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise'
```