# Rails4 + devise + mongoid - `require': cannot load such file -- mongoid/version (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use rails4 with mongoid and devise. I have this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'devise'
```

`bundle install` is successfull. But when i try to start `rails server`, I get this error

```
Exiting
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- mongoid/version (LoadError)
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/rails.rb:34:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
```

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having same problem, just make following change in Gemfile

```
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
```

If Devise continues problem, change devise also

```
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Don't forget to bundle! :)

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513066/devise-with-rails-4, you do not need to specify the rails4 branch anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bundle update
```

If this didn't work, try including the moped gem

```
gem 'moped'
```