# Getting error in rails after installing devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am getting this error after installing devise for users

```
C:3:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execut
e_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rail
s::Application::RoutesReloader:0x3900780 @paths=["C:/ror/wishlistize/config/rout
es.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x393a140>]> (RuntimeE
rror)
        from C:131071:in `execute_if_updated'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/applic
ation/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each
_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_
component_from'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_c
onnected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_
component'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railti
e/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/ror/wishlistize/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure if its because of devise

here's my routes file

```
Wishlistize::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
end
```

and environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Wishlistize::Application.initialize!
```

I get this when i run rake db:migrate
User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: Are you using the Rails4 compatible version of devise? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513066/devise-with-rails-4).

Comment: gem 'devise', '3.0.0' I am

Comment: Can you post your devise model? (Something like User). I suspect you've got some leftover `attr_accessible` (which have been replaced with strong parameters in Rails 4). This is usually a result of upgrading an existing Rails app.

Comment: okay. I am posting it here

Comment: this is a fresh new project btw.

Comment: This was a silly ovesight. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figure this out. I did not actually run `rails g devise:install`  but directly `rails g devise:user` according to the tutorial that I had read. It seems that was causing the problem. I installed the edge version and it became clear.