# Adding devise gem to a Rails 4 / mysql project (table users already exists)

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm a total newbie with Ruby, Rails, Rake, MySQL (on Ubuntu/bash/command line) and *devise* (warden 1.2.3, devise 3.0.4). I must continue with what have been done so far : the Rails 4 project is working and linked to a MySQL database (full, populated with users and data).  I'm able to change controllers and views.

I must add devise to the project.  I'm reading this : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise . My class name is *User*. So I did `rails generate devise User`.

When I do `rake db:migrate` I have this error : `Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: ...` of course, since I already have a *users* table in my project.

Whatever I read ( [Devise with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513066/devise-with-rails-4) ), it's always about *create the User model*, never *how to plug devise on a pre-existing User model*.

What document should I read ? Which file I must edit to tell devise "this is my user model and table:" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Ruby/Rails is brand new for you, and you're lost.. (like I was...).

- **Look for the migration file** (*migration-name*.rb) in "/yourproject/db/migrate/". This file was generated by `rails generate devise User` (*User* can by **any** Model, like *UserAdmin* or *Client* ...).  This file tells you the modifications Devise will do to the database (what it needs).
- Look at this file carefully and make sure that your database match the requirements.  If you run `rake db:migrate` rake will attempt to modify your database.  Maybe this is your error (attempt to create a table User, since your table User is already created).
- Modify your migration file. You may also change your database manually and delete the migration file (if you don't care to keep track of your migrations); in this last case, of course, you don't have to run the *rake* command.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Devise `getting-started guide`, and *intelligently* apply the manual steps to your current project where necessary.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

Comment: Add Devise to your model, instead of creating a new one. My Guess is that you created a new model, but you didn't delete your old migration.