# Rails 5 Generate devise with already created user table in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I know that this may have been asked a lot, but the answers are fuzzy in somways... Basically what i wanna know in a direct way, it's how can i link my table **key.tbl_ctrl_usuario** with the devise gem...

[Devise with rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419030/devise-with-rails-5)

[Adding devise gem to rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666790/adding-devise-gem-to-a-rails-4-mysql-project-table-users-already-exists)

These are the links that i check, but the answers i cannot understand completly...

I have my database in Postgresql and my table **USER** it's declared in this way

```
CREATE TABLE key.tbl_ctrl_usuario
(
  idusuario integer NOT NULL,
  nombreusuario character varying(150) NOT NULL,
  clave character varying(300) NOT NULL,
  rol character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  estado boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_ctrl_usuario_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idusuario),
  CONSTRAINT tbl_ctrl_usuario_idusuario_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idusuario)
      REFERENCES key.tbl_ctrl_empleados (idempleado) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE key.tbl_ctrl_usuario
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

You needs to add devise required columns in your table link email, password etc. for simplicity you can rename your table name to user [check here how to rename migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471416/how-do-you-write-a-migration-to-rename-an-activerecord-model-and-its-table-in-ra) and check out this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns) for generate devise with already created table.

Answer (score 0):

Rename table to users on your migration. The existent user table contains the users of postgres. And you should use variables in english not spanish